# Handling fcm notification click

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using fcm to send messages. The messages arrive to the app, but when the user clicks on the notification, t it supposed to open a link but it just opens the app. My manifest is like this

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
```

Where the notification is supposed to be handled :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("rateUpdate")) {
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("market://details?id=tino.varconn.com.fastnetworks")));
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException unused) {
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tino.varconn.com.fastnetworks")));
        }
    }
```

When sending the message, I always make sure that in the key, value text boxes I put `rateUpdate`. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Can you please put a break point on extras(Bundle) to check the value of bundle.Also please confirm that your if-check is working and your code is reaching at that point where you are opening the URL.Thank you

Comment: where are you handling your intent ? can you show the class ?

Comment: in the mainActivity class, in the onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Inside FirebaseMessagingService class you can get content from push notification and build your own Notification

```
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification()
        String title = notification.getTitle()
        String body = notification.getBody();
        //now you can build and show your own notification
    }
```

with `.setContentIntent()` method, where you can set any Activity you want to start.

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = ...
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, destinationClass);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
            0);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```